# Loop through Excel sheets to extract individual cell values using Python Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to loop through multiple Excel sheets to extract cell values (in this example, it'd be A1, B2, A3), and display values from each sheet in a row (see examples below). The source file is a bit messy, with row labels ('Fruit name', 'object type', 'count') that has been removed for simplification.

I was able to extract cell values from a single column (see current code), but need helping getting values scattered throughout two columns. In my real-life project, I have many more cells, so it is important that the solution is scalable. I tried Openpyxl last week, but have reverted to pandas as pd seems to be more versatile. Ideas on how to write clean code for this would be much appreciated!

## Sheet Format

```
    A     B
0 Apples
1       Fruit
2  5
```

## Desired output

Values from multiple sheets displayed as rows in a new sheet:

```
 A       B       C
Apples  Fruit    5
Cilanto Herb     4
```

## Current code

```
result=[]
for i in File.sheet_names:
    df = pd.read_excel(File.xlsx', sheet_name=i)
    cells = df.iloc[[0, 2], [1]]
    result.append(cells)
result = pd.concat(result, axis=1).T
```

Comment: Hey there! I don't fully understand your source excel format. I can't see any structure there: It seems like 'A' holds some object names and 'B' holds the type of the corresponding object. E.g. 'Apples' are 'Fruit'. So why is it in different rows? Doesn't seem to make any sense. Any why is a "5" there in Row 2?

Comment: You're right, the structure doesn't make sense - I've modified my post to clarify. "The source file is a bit messy, with row labels ('Fruit name', 'object type', 'count') that I have omitted for simplicity purposes."

Answer (score 1):

Given we have one excel file with the following format:

**Sheet 1**

```
    A       B       C
1   Apples  Fruit   1
2   Bananas Fruit   7
3   Chives  Herbs   6
```

**Sheet 2**

```
    A           B       C
1   Cilanto     Fruit   1
2   Pineapple   Fruit   7
```

You could do something like this to have all data in one pandas data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import string


character_number_mapping = {string.ascii_lowercase[i]:i for i in range(len(string.ascii_lowercase))}


def col(cell_name: str):
    character = cell_name.split('-')[0]
    
    return character_number_mapping[character.lower()]

    
def row(cell_name: str):
    row_number = int(cell_name.split('-')[1])
    
    return row_number - 1


excel_file = pd.ExcelFile('ExampleExcel.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')

df = pd.DataFrame()
for sheet_name in excel_file.sheet_names:
    sheet_data = {'A': [], 'B': [], 'C': []}
    df_tmp = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name, header=None)
    sheet_data['A'].append(df_tmp.loc[row('A-2'), col('A-2')])
    sheet_data['B'].append(df_tmp.loc[row('B-1'), col('B-1')])
    sheet_data['C'].append(df_tmp.loc[row('C-2'), col('C-2')])
    sheet_data['A'].append(df_tmp.loc[row('A-1'), col('A-1')])
    sheet_data['B'].append(df_tmp.loc[row('B-2'), col('B-2')])
    sheet_data['C'].append(df_tmp.loc[row('C-1'), col('C-1')])
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(sheet_data)])

df.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']
    
df.head()
```

prints

```
    A           B       C
0   Bananas     Fruit   7
1   Apples      Fruit   1
0   Pineapple   Herbs   4
1   Cilanto     Fruit   2
```

If you want the index to be monotoneous, apply a `reset_index(drop=True)` afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the example! How could the code be modified to extract specific cells (e.g. A1, B2, A3, A17, so forth)? In my project, I'm hoping to extract only relevant cell values that are spread out in different cells

Comment: This got a little bit messy now. Please consider introducing a function for extracting single rows. And please note:
- This is only an approach, you could achieve that in a numerous different ways
- This currently only works for a-z, if there are more than 26 cols, you have to change the code

Comment: Thank you so much for the ideas! This also made me realize that cleaning up the source file will help me go a long way

Comment: Absolutely right :) feel free to mark the answer as right